# Need CAPL script to find fin or RST messages over TCP connection - DOIP

Tags: ethernet, capl, canoe, tcpsocket, automotive

Can someone help me with CAPL script to find FIN /RST messages over canoe trace window? This is for DOIP module - I want it to check the RST/FIN from tester as well as ECU(as we specify)

Basically we want to identify the RST/FIN messages over canoe trace window and check from which IP or mac address its coming . This helps us to identify whether we are receiving it from ECU or tester

We implemented it is using python by taking the logs from Wireshark, this is not being useful since we are not observing this messages in Wireshark which we are seeing currently appearing over canoe trace window
Unable to find any help on CAPL script to implement this,, hence need support on the same

```
on ethernetPacket *
 {
 if((this.dir == tx) && (this.tcp.IsAvailable()))     
   {
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<=60;i++)
    {
     write(" %d TCP packet bytes %X",i,this.Byte(i));

    }
  } 
 }
```

Comment: You can access the flags for each TCP packet like this: `packet.tcp.Flags`. As you do not show a single line of code, it is impossible to help you further.

Comment: on ethernetPacket *
 {
if((this.dir == tx) && (this.tcp.IsAvailable()))     
   {
  int i; 
       for(i=0;i<=60;i++)
          {
        write(" %d TCP socket creation %X",i,this.Byte(i));

          }
 } 
 }  
Here is the snippet that we are using to find the TCP packets, basically we are trying to analyze tcp packets SYNACK, FIN ACK, RST ACK

When I am using this code its printing all the ethernet packets flowing on bus instead of printing tcp sockets, please help me to identify the issue

I

Comment: As said, the TCP flags can be accessed as - in your case - `this.tcp.Flags`

Comment: I tried this, but its not working. Getting the error member tcp.flags not found.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP flags can be accessed using the member `<packet>.tcp.Flags` (or `flags` as CAPL is not case-sensitive).

In your case something as follows should work:

```
on ethernetPacket *
{
  byte RST = 0x04;

  if((this.dir == tx) && (this.tcp.IsAvailable()))     
  {
    if(this.tcp.Flags & RST == RST)
    {
      write("RST packet received");
    }
  } 
}
```

The order of the flag bits is the same as specified by the TCP protocol.

Comment: When we consider TCP packets like synack,finack,rstack (packet length is 60 bytes each)-bytes of this packets will be almost similar and only few byte position changes will be there which specifies which packet it is. May I know which byte I can consider from the packet to differentiate between these messages?(synack,rstack,finack)

Comment: The TCP flags, i.e. SYN, URG, ACK, PSH, FIN, and RST can be accessed in byte `this.tcp.Flags`. A _synack_ package has the bits SYN and ACK set.